# how to saved the iterate input in file handling in python

Tags: python

I want to saved my output in my file handling. I made an iteration and the only output that is showing is only the last input.

Here is my code:

```
import os
num_string = []
strings = int(input("Enter how many lines of text: "))
for i in range (0,strings):
    element = str(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
    (num_string.append(element))

for name in num_string:
    print(name) 
f = open("D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob", "w")
f.write("%s\n" %(name))
f = open("D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob", "a")
f = open("D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob", "r")
```

This is what it shows in my code:

How many lines of text: 3

1. a
2. b
3. c

Output shows in file handling:

c

**My ideal output:**

I want it to read like:

a

b

c

Comment: You don't write any data in your loop.

Comment: Your code loops through `num_string` and prints the contents. But *after that loop terminates*, it then writes to a file. At that point, `name` contains the last value it had in the loop.  Move the `open()` call to before the `for` loop (and decide if you want `"w"` or `"a"`, don't do both).  Put the `write()` call *inside* the `for` loop, next to the `print()` call. Because you want the file to have what the `print()` calls show. And remember to call `close()` on the file *after* the `for` loop.

Comment: Which for should I write the open? The first or second one

Answer (score 0):

Here is the advice in my comment, spelled out.

```
num_string = []
strings = int(input("Enter how many lines of text: "))
for i in range (0,strings):
    element = str(input(str(i + 1) + ". "))
    (num_string.append(element))

f = open(r""D:/VB/QUIZ NLTK/conll.iob"", "w")      # Open the file before the loop
for name in num_string:
    print(name) 
    f.write("%s\n" %(name))                        # Write to the file inside the loop

f.close()                                          # Close the file after the loop
```

I've left out `import os` because your code doesn't use it. Other than that, the code is as close to your original as is consistent with getting it to work as you expect.